# flume - Streaming data from Twitter API into HDFS

Tags: apache, hadoop, twitter, cloudera, flume

I have spent the previous weeks working on streaming Twitter data into a Hadoop (**Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.3**) server by using Flume (**Flume 1.5.0-cdh5.4.3**) in a local VM running CentOS 6.6.

Initially, I tried using the built-in Twitter source that comes as a default library on Flume and it worked but the data apparently wasn't properly encoded and later this was confirmed as a known issue by the Cloudera team (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Flume-Twitter-data-looks-corrupt/td-p/48095).

This method used class name **org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource**, properly setup on flume.conf file.

Later, I tried using a custom Twitter JAR source which can be found on Cloudera's website (http://files.cloudera.com/samples/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) and through many other tutorials but this led me to another issue while receiving the status streams from the Twitter API, where the application gets stuck.

```
2017-05-25 09:51:37,875 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[initializing]) 
[INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 
Establishing connection.
2017-05-25 09:52:10,545 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) 
[INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 
Connection established.
2017-05-25 09:52:10,546 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) 
[INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 
Receiving status stream.
```

This method used class name **com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource** which reportedly is no longer working and has been replaced by **org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource**.
The required files were setup as shown below:

1) **flume.conf**

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource #(OLD CLASS)
#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource #(NEW CLASS)
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <consumerKey>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <consumerSecret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <accessToken>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <accessTokenSecret>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 100
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 100000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.callTimeout = 30000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

2) **flume-env.sh**

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx500m"
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/flume-twitter-source.jar"
```

So, any idea of what is going on? Can anyone run Flume based on this setup? Is there a new method of connecting Flume to the Twitter API that I'm not aware of?
Thanks!

Comment: did you check flume.log?

Comment: It's looping on "Checking file:/etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf for changes" while using the custom JAR source.
`2017-05-25 10:50:11,469 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Receiving stream]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] Twitter Stream consumer-1[Receiving stream]
2017-05-25 10:50:38,926 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:126)] Checking file:/etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf for changes`